# #1054-Unknown column 'userid' in 'field list' in mysql. Getting error when i am importing a file containing this table in mysql through xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `authtype` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'mysql',
  `disabled` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `logonchange` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `expiry` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ldapdn` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cookieid` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastchanged` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `first_name` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `payroll_number` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2234 ;

INSERT INTO `user` (`userid`, `username`, `password`, `authtype`, `disabled`, `logonchange`, `expiry`, `ldapdn`, `cookieid`, `lastchanged`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `payroll_number`) VALUES
(1, 'administrator', '200ceb26807d6bf99fd6f4f0d1ca54d4', 'mysql', 0, 0, 0, '', 'e6f33989529daf141bd1406702b995fc', 1155190068, NULL, NULL, NULL, ''),
(2224, 'staff', '1253208465b1efa876f982d8a9e73eef', 'mysql', 0, 0, 0, 'NULL', '972b26e91f1a089cb0cafb16cbeb422c', 1156372109, NULL, NULL, NULL, ''),
(2233, 'guest', '', 'mysql', 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, '');
```

Comment: Query looks ok, are you sure that the data is imported on the correct DB ? and also check if there is any trigger associated on user table `after insert` or `before insert`

Comment: while importing the file may be `sql` or `csv` and see the file entries where the columns are named correctly or not.

Comment: @Riad There does not seem to be problem with names....

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty ...Everything seems to be fine to me....any way i   could  show the whole file?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late. :) See `AUTO_INCREMENT=2234` in your code?

It says auto increment starts with **2234** which is correct for any further entries but when importing we are inserting with userid = 1 for the first entry which breaks the rule. This is the reason why you are getting error. You can remove the auto increment part from the `create` table statement and use the below statement after the `Insert` statements

```
ALTER TABLE user AUTO_INCREMENT = 2234;
```

Errors like: #1054-Unknown column 'xxxx' in 'field list' can be solved by simple editing the import file.